# Security public network

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, security, firewall

Which precautions should have to take when I will use a public network ?

I use Ubuntu 18.04 with a Windows 10 dual boot (on same disk) and I also use a private network with other Windows computers.

I have already activated ufw with default laws, uninstall samba and I don't install wine.

I see that I should use a VPN, is it correct ?
Do I use differents users account depending on which networks I am connected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are doing, if only watching youtube cute cat videos, I would not worry too much.  If doing banking or sending secure personal information, would at minimum use a decent paid VPN(some have free option if using little). Secure personal info includes signing in to websites.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But there are no problems with dual boot for security of my computer and my private network ? 
And using differents "users" with differents permission depending on which network I am using is useful or useless ?

Comment: If I am reading you right, dual boot is almost like having two separate computers, but you can only use one at a time. Ubuntu and a decent VPN is as safe or safer than windows and VPN.  On Linux the difference in users permissions is usually if they have sudo access to change ubuntu. All users are treated as regular user(not administrator).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if it's not properly formuled but I wan't to "disable" the connection between my 2 OS ( now the folder "Windows network" in nautilus isn't accesible ) and I want to control the communication between my computer and my private network ( I think that a firewall can do that, is it correct ?) I already enabled ufw on ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: Think you only have to unmount, but the two OSs will not communicate together.  You must do an operation such as moving a file from one(ubuntu) to windows. You cannot use a program on one OS from the other.  One OS will be shutdown(unable to work) when you are using the other.

Comment: Ok, So a malware cannot infect my windows when I use my ubuntu session ( the 2 OS are on the same disk ) ?
Really thanks to taking your time.

Comment: No, it can be done,but you have to work very hard to do it. you would have to download the malware, then you would have to copy or move the malware to windows yourself.  99% of malware will not infect Ubuntu, even if downloaded to it.

Comment: I have seen that use a firewall when using public network is recommended. I install ufw and gufw and deny incoming connection and allow outcoming connection, that's adequate or I need to add some rules ? (I don't know if I should create a new question ). Thanks